# Characterization of distributions as sums of locally integrable functions and derivatives of delta

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

The space of locally integrable functions embeds in the space of (standard) distributions. Additionally, every distribution can be thought of as a multiple derivative of some continuous function.

Does this imply that every distribution can be thought of as the sum of a locally integrable function, and a countable sum of translations of derivatives of the Dirac delta distribution?

In other words, loosely thinking, does every distribution have a "function" part, and a "delta" part?

I would like to think that this is what's implied by the theorem that every distribution is the n'th derivative of a continuous function -- in other words, that the "delta part" of any derivative will appear at the parts where the continuous function isn't differentiable. But what about functions like the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), which is continuous yet nowhere differentiable?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would imply that every measure on R is a sum of an absolutely continuous measure and an atomic measure. But this fails to account for, e.g., the Cantor measure (i.e. the measure supported on the Cantor set).

Comment: @MikeHawk. That sounds very like what the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem (as Folland calls it) states:  If $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite signed measure and $\mu$ as $\sigma$-finite positive measure then there exist unique $\sigma$-finite signed measures $\lambda$ and $\rho$ such that $\lambda$ and $\rho$ are mutually singular, $\rho$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$ and $\nu = \lambda + \rho.$

Comment: @md2perpe: Yes, that's what I had in mind. There's a refinement for measures on R^n (which probably extends to Borel measures on Hausdorff spaces) which further decomposes $\lambda$ into an atomic part (countable sum of delta measures) and an absolutely singular part (meaning the measure is mutually singular against $\mu$, but the cdf is continuous).

Comment: What would be the locally integrable function and what would be the countable sum of translations of derivatives of $\delta$ for the distribution $u(x) = (\ln x)'$?